# c++ class declaration when same routine, different member variable type

Tags: c++, class

I'm trying to make a class something like this

```
class IPclass {
  void SendData();

  io_service io_service_;
  tcp::socket tcp_socket_{io_service_};
};

class UDSclass {
  void SendData();

  io_service io_service_;
  local::stream_protocol::socket tcp_socket_{io_service_};
};
```

The thing is, IPclass and UDSclass have same routine with same member variables with one difference: socket type.

I want to make one class named SessionClass instead of these two classes.

These are options I tried and reasons of failure.

- Union: Cannot use same variable name. (I want to use **var** rather than **u.var1** on methods)
- Template: Have to define template typename on each constructor.
- Using 2 different variable in one class: Have to use method with different parameters

Is there any suggestion or known solution for this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you ever heard of inheritance?

Comment: If the definition of `SendData` will be essentially the same in both, a template sounds like a good answer - could you expand on what troubles you had using a class template? If the functions are rather different, polymorphism is probably the way to go.

Comment: Templates. Same routine with same member variables, different types. That's exactly what templates are for. The whole of C++ is built on that. If you don't like it, perhaps you need a different language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a templated class:

```
template <typename NetworkType>
class NetworkClass
{
    NetworkType tcp_socket_{io_service_};
};
```

and then use:

```
using IPclass = NetworkClass<tcp::socket>;
```

If you need more than this, you can use type traits to define more advanced behaviors without dynamic polymorphism.